# Provide consistent schema for varying JSON data in pyspark glue job

Tags: aws-glue

I'm looking for an approach or example to handle deeply nested JSON data that will vary between glue job runs, allowing me to output consistent parquet schema's.

The current approach is as follows:

- Kinesis Firehose outputs JSON data into a landing zone
- Glue job, with bookmarks enabled, reads in new files as a dynamic frame, unnests and converts to parquet, and then sinks to S3 whilst updating glue catalog

The issue with this appraoch is that the schema (inferred from the JSON files) can vary between job runs. This will result in the output parquet files having different column orders and schema changes, which breaks columnar storage/tables.

I've struggled to get a crawler working correctly on the json source data, as it seems to detect multiple tables, possibly trying to infer consistent schemas within the dataset.

I do have a glue notebook setup that creates a schema from the entire dataset, and I'd like to use this. The schema is 100's of columns, with some nested structures, so it's not feasible to manually create this table in the glue catalog.

Is it possible to use this schema I've created to generate a glue table + schema, without actually writing any of the data from the dynamic frame out?